# Не могу запарсить значение из json-строки

Tags: php

Есть json-строка следующего вида:

```
{["name_ru"]=> string(8) "Киев"}
```

Пытаюсь парсить следующими способами, и выводится либо NULL, либо вообще пустая строка:

```
$geo = !$is_bot ? json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.sypexgeo.net/json/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']), true) : [];
echo $geo->name_ru; // выводит пустую строку
print_r($geo->{"name_ru"}); //выводит пустую строку
var_dump($geo->{'name_ru'}); //выводит NULL
//var_dump($geo); // выводит массив с валидными данными
```

Как мне получить нужное значение?

Comment: 1) это не JSON: `{["name_ru"]=> string(8) "Киев"}` 2) SxGeo возвращает совсем другие данные 3) проверяйте возврат `file_get_contents()` (может вы превысили лимиты или ещё что не так) 4) покажите IP, для которого идёт запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странный у вас какой-то JSON указан в начале. И вот это тоже непонятно:

```
echo $geo->name_ru
```

SxGeo возвращает такую структуру, после `json_decode()`:

```
Array
(
    [ip] => 111.222.333.444
    [city] => Array
        (
            [id] => 498817
            [lat] => 59.93863
            [lon] => 30.31413
            [name_ru] => Санкт-Петербург
            [name_en] => Saint Petersburg
            [name_de] => Sankt Petersburg
            [name_fr] => Saint-Pétersbourg
            [name_it] => San Pietroburgo
            [name_es] => San Petersburgo
            [name_pt] => São Petersburgo
            [okato] => 40
            [vk] => 2
            [population] => 5191690
        )
    [region] => Array
        (
            [id] => 536203
            [lat] => 59.92
            [lon] => 30.25
            [name_ru] => Санкт-Петербург
            [name_en] => Sankt-Peterburg
            [name_de] => Sankt Petersburg
            [name_fr] => Saint-Pétersbourg
            [name_it] => San Pietroburgo
            [name_es] => San Petersburgo
            [name_pt] => São Petersburgo
            [iso] => RU-SPE
            [timezone] => Europe/Moscow
            [okato] => 40
            [auto] => 78, 98, 178
            [vk] => 0
            [utc] => 3
        )
    [country] => Array
        (
            [id] => 185
            [iso] => RU
            [continent] => EU
            [lat] => 60
            [lon] => 100
            [name_ru] => Россия
            [name_en] => Russia
            [name_de] => Russland
            [name_fr] => Russie
            [name_it] => Russia
            [name_es] => Rusia
            [name_pt] => Rússia
            [timezone] => Europe/Moscow
            [area] => 17100000
            [population] => 140702000
            [capital_id] => 524901
            [capital_ru] => Москва
            [capital_en] => Moscow
            [cur_code] => RUB
            [phone] => 7
            [neighbours] => GE,CN,BY,UA,KZ,LV,PL,EE,LT,FI,MN,NO,AZ,KP
            [vk] => 1
            [utc] => 3
        )
    [error] => 
    [request] => -8
    [created] => 2016.10.08
    [timestamp] => 1475955522
)
```

Стало быть, русское название города добывается следующим образом:

```
// без IP будет обрабатываться IP машины/прокси, откуда идёт запрос
$data = file_get_contents( 'http://api.sypexgeo.net/json/' );
if( $data )
{
    $geo = json_decode( $data, true );
    print $geo['city']['name_ru']; // <<< вот так!
}
```